# Magento 2.X: Module URL rewrite

Tags: magento2, module, url-rewrite, routing

Magento ver. 2.3.2

I am writing a Magento 2 module. I'm trying to re-write a CMS page URL:

https://www.test.com/url-test/cat1/cat2/cat3/

https://www.test.com/url-test?path=/cat1/cat2/cat3/

I have a widget on the CMS page url-test that handles the logic of what is passed in GET['path'].

I cannot get the Router to fire at all (display the die() cmd). I've played with different values for the di sortOrder. I've tried overriding default routers. All to no avail.

I don't have a /etc/frontend/routes.xml file as I don't think I need it.

/etc/frontend/dii.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test_router" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Me\MyModule\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

/Controller/Router.php:

```
namespace Me\MyModule\Controller;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    private $actionFactory;

   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory)
    {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        die("test Router");
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

die() will not work. Use logger concept.

This is the wrong files name `etc/frontend/dii.xml` it should be `etc/frontend/di.xml`.

**using SortOrder value 1 is very dangerous.**

In this case routing should be between **60(cms route) and 100 (default route)**.

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html

Comment: facepalm! di.xml fixed it